# DataFrame cell access low performance

Tags: python, performance, pandas, optimization

I am using a `DataFrame` instead of a regular `dict` for performance since they use `numpy` arrays internally. However, accessing a cell seems to have a terrible impact in performance.

My `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=models1, index=models2).fillna(STATE1).stack()
```

The types of the columns are models are Django `models.Model` subclasses and `STATE1` and all other states are simply integers.

I often need to check if `df[m1, m2] == state_n` but apparently merely accessing the cell `df[m1, m2]` takes a long time: when I run the whole thing where this statement is used the total execution time is 0.15 seconds, but when that statement is included it takes 0.25 seconds. This is a massive increase for an operation that should be `O(1)` and the statement is only being executed 9216 times.

What is going on here? How can I optimize its performance?

Comment: If the *only* purpose of using Pandas versus NumPy is for index identifiers and row headings, I suggest you refactor logic to use NumPy. You then get the performance of arrays in contiguous memory blocks, albeit with a potential overhead of indexing logic.

Comment: @jpp I really want that. But I need to be able to identify a cell as if it were a dictionary: `values[m1][m2]`, they need to be indexed. I don't think I can do that with `numpy`.

Comment: Can't you simply put your NumPy arrays into ordinary dicts? If indexing into a dict is too slow for you then you will need a solution that is fine-tuned to your particular data structures.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker well if I create a separate NumPy array for each key then I would be defeating the purpose of having a whole numpy matrix wouldn't I?